# Walking through python list comprehension

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to understand list comprehension in python using this example -

```
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    stream = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.streaming"]
    if stream:
```

The above example is using the api from discord.py. Streaming is a member activity - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#activity . ActivityType.streaming is a type - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ActivityType

What's going on in this loop? I'll try and walkthrough what I may know. So if `(i.type)` returns as a string then it would be looping through the characters in the stream list? I'm confused. `after.activites` is the member's CURRENT activity. So it'd be streaming. What exactly does `(i.type)` represent what how is the loop interacting with `after.activites`?

Getting lost. Could someone walk me through the steps of what's happening here? Thank you!

Comment: "How does this code work?" is generally considered off-topic on this site. You'll likely get better responses to questions like these in the future on https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython

Comment: Does https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+how+does+a+list+comprehension+work help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. This is not a tutoring service; we don't deal in explaining the fundamentals of the language or talking through someone else's code. We deal in helping you with the process of *writing your own* code.

Comment: My apologies. Will review the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions can be mechanically transformed into loops. This comprehension is equivalent to the code

```py
stream = []
for i in after.activities:
    if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.streaming":
        stream.append(i)
```

---

Unrelated, it is somewhat atypical to compare the type of something by first converting it to a string and then comparing the resulting string. Knowing nothing else, I would expect to see instead the line

```py
    if i.type == ActivityType.streaming
```

or perhaps a `isinstance()` instead of direct type comparison if there can be meaningful subtypes.